# Package doc and glossaries together cause problem

Tags: glossaries

If I comment out `\RecordChanges` below it compiles and works, otherwise I get:

```
    Package glossaries Warning: No file defined for glossary `[' on input line 13.

! Extra \endcsname.
\@@do@wrglossary ...\csname glo@#1@type\endcsname 
                                                  ]{\string \glossaryentry {...
l.13 A \gls{sample} 
                    entry
```

Here is the minimum example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{doc}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\RecordChanges

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample}, description={a sample entry}}

\begin{document}

A \gls{sample} entry

Plurals: \glspl{sample}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! While the `glossaries` package states to be compatible with `doc` (provided it's loaded before `glossaries`, as you do), it seems that `\RecordChanges` confuses `\@wrglossary`.

Comment: It seems that moving also `\RecordChanges` before loading `glossaries` fixes the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `\RecordChanges` is simply `\makeglossary`. But issuing it after loading `glossaries` puts the system into an unstable state.

So the correct method for making the two package go along together is not only loading `doc` before `glossaries` as stated in the documentation of the latter package, but also issue `\RecordChanges` *before* loading `glossaries`.

I'd also load `hyperref` after `doc`. So here's a working combination:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{doc}
\RecordChanges

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample}, description={a sample entry}}

\begin{document}

A \gls{sample} entry

Plurals: \glspl{sample}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Maybe `glossaries` could some other tricks to allow issuing `\RecordChanges` before or after loading it, but I'll leave this as an exercise for Nicola Talbot. `;-)`

Comment: ooh an exercise for the reader, I mean, for the package writer. `:)`

Comment: `glossaries` does a check for `doc` near the start of the package, so I could add in some code there to fix this.